# Converting Office files to PDF using SaveAs

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, office-interop

I have a question about saving the Microsoft Office format file like doc, xls to PDF. I am using the SavesAs option in VB.Net to convert the files to PDF programatically. However, I need to open the file differently to achieve this.

If file is an Excel, then I need to open it using excel API's and then perform SaveAs. Similarly with Word documents. Is there a way so that I can open this documents generically and then use SaveAs option to convert them to PDF irrespective of opening the files?

Answer (score 0):

The Word API and Excel API are two distinct APIs, even though they may both have a `SaveAs` method. You will not be able to use the same call for both file types.